Is this Groß-Deutschland 1938-1948 poster real (and produced/published by Nazi Germany)?

Source
I found the anticlockwise swastikas strange.
The poster is supposed to be from 1938.
Some Reddit comments suggest this (or a very similar poster) is fake.
(The above poster appears in the movie One Life.)

Northern Spain, Greece, Eastern Turkey definitely look suspicious. Also not distinguishing between annexed (i.e. Austria, Sudetes, Danzig) and occupied territories.

Also timeline is wrong. Yugoslavia was occupied in 1941 and France, Denmark and Benelux (but not Switzerland) in 1940.

The swastika is wrong: 1) it turns to the left, should be to the right 2) it's too thin.

@Jan I imagine that discrepancies about the timeline could be explainable if the poster was from 1938 and displayed not realizations, but a plan for the future. Still looks like a forgery to me, but I will wait for an answer by someone more knowledgeable.

FWIW, The handwritten country names aside each map (По́льша for Poland, Румыния for Romania, etc.) are in Russian.

The listed source in a Russian library archive has an associated note with the document-anyone fluent in Russian might be able to glean some more info there. It appears to be dated in 1939.

The linked source contains a letter signed by military intelligence komdiv A.G. Orlov to marshal Voroshilov dated April 7 1939, which the Yeltsin Presidential Library attests is genuine. It is part of this collection. Orlov says the Nazis distributed the leaflet in Prague and Transcarpathian Ruthenia - however there are no details on who specifically produced the leaflet, or why.

France is interesting. It doesn't look exactly like Vichy France (summer 1940 onwards), but fairly close. Where did that come from, if the map is from 1938?

A CBS news article Inside Nicholas Winton's scrapbook has images from a scrapbook kept by Nicholas Winton.  An image containing most of the information you see in the above poster can be seen here:

The news articles caption to that image:

Historians believe Nicholas Winton was closely following what the
Nazis were planning. According to Dr. David Silberklang, senior
historian at Yad Vashem's Research Institute, Winton collected maps
while in Prague. This map seems to look ahead to what Germany saw as
its future in the coming decade. It features the Nazi slogan, "Ein
Volk, ein Reich, ein Führer." One people, one empire, one leader.

The original scrapbook is held in the Yad Vashem Archives . The same page there.
So, as noted in comments we can see that at least two of this document exist, both apparently dated between 1938 (Winton's book) and 1939 (the Russian library documentation). The likelihood of a forgery would seem quite low. @SPavels translation of the note connected to the Russian source indicates it was a leaflet and that 'the Nazis distributed the leaflet in Prague and Transcarpathian Ruthenia'

@nuffa has brought up a couple of links to another distinct version of this map, also purported to be from 1937. The Imperial War Museum has a copy of A British propaganda poster from 1939 which has as an inset another map similar to the one above, but with slight variations (yet another strange swastika). A copy is also found in The Cornell digital collections,which also has this poster dated at about 1939:

The Cornell site does have a comment in its notes concerning the validity of this map as a Nazi publication:

The support for the poster is a "Secret Nazi Map - circulated in 1937"
(not further identified). In fact, "it is highly unlikely that the
Nazis would ever have allowed something as incendiary as this map to
be printed or disseminated. It is more probably that it was invented
by the anonymous propagandist to lend credibility to his message."
Curtis 2016, 115.

(Unfortunately, so far, I have not located the Curtis source cited)
So we can see a consistent accepted dating of these items to 1937-1939. We also have at least one expert cited believing they are the product of anti-Nazi propaganda, not a product of the Nazis themselves.
As I mentioned above, they seem to be legitimately items produced between 1937 and 1939, but who made them and to what purpose we can only speculate on.
(To me it is not inconceivable that the second map in the British poster is a handmade copy of one of the other maps made for the sake of the propaganda poster, and the propaganda artist noted the incorrect swastikas and changed it to something he considered more correct. But that is pure speculation.)

+1, though it would also be interesting to know whether this map was created by the Nazis themselves.

Unknown at least at this point. I can place it to this scapbook, but where Winton found it would be the next step. The obious cut and paste (literally-scrapbook style) means it might have been a poster or pamphlet, or he found it in a newspaper article while in Prague.

The different qulity of the paper and the absence of handwritten words proves that this and the OP are two different occurence of a same poster. So it most probably has been printed in series (by whom is another qestion...) and isn't just an artefact of a prank.

@Jan According to OP's source, at least Red Army intelligence seemed to think so. But "the Nazis" covers everyone from Hitler and his squabbling cabinet on down to a random Hans with a printing press and an active imagination.

"likelihood of a forgery quite low" - OTOH, they did not plan to attack UK (or Scandinavia), so that looks more like a Russian point-of-view.  Also, France is suspicious, as noted in other comment.

Any ideas about the direction of the swastikas?

This is also reproduced in Maurice Pasquelot, Les Dossiers Secrets de la Marine: London-Vichy 1940-1944. Paris: Nouvelles Editions Latines 1977, p. 32 (Google scan), which claims that this was a poster posted in "all public places" in Germany in spring of 1939.

The Imperial War Museum dates this poster to 1937: "HERE'S THE EVIDENCE ABOVE is a photograph of a map issued by the Nazis in 1937. Note the hooked Sudeten Swastika, for the map was found in Czechoslovakia."

@njuffa That looks to be the item claimed to be a fraud in the reddit post linked by the OP. Can't really speak to the authenticity of these, since they all appear to be later renderings, not the original publications. If they are legit it speaks to the fact that multiple publishers were responsible for producing these items. It would be interesting to get a date on the imperial war museum item however. Funny that the war museum item claims "secret Nazi map"  and the book says posted in "all public places".
